# Huxley? Agnoticism and Christianity. Both at the same time?

Tags: belief

Are they call agnostic theist? I believe it's wrong to say I'm certain of things. But I want to believe in God? Knowledge and belief is two different things right?

Or did I not understand Huxley's definition of agnosticism correctly?

Also, what do Christians think of agnosticism?

Comment: Welcome to the site!  I'm not sure exactly what you'reasking here... This next is just standard to help new visitors avoid misunderstanding the site (as I did at first.)  As a new visitor, I'd recommend checking out the following posts, which are meant to help newcomers "learn the ropes": [the help page](http://christianity.stackexchange.com/help) and [How we are different than other sites?](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/1808/how-we-are-different-than-other-sites)

Comment: see also 
[What makes a good focused question?](http://meta.christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/690/what-makes-a-good-focused-question)

Comment: Some consider Eastern Orthodoxy to be Christian agnosticism, because we believe God is unknowable *in his essence.*

Comment: It would help if you started by quoting Huxley's definition of agnosticism.

Answer (score 2):

Since I am unsure as to what you preceived from Huxley, I am taking the liberty of inserting the most common concept of agnosticism.

The American Heritage Dictionary of the English Language

```
ag•nos•ti•cism n.

1. The doctrine that certainty about first principles or absolute truth is unattainable and that only perceptual
phenomena are objects of exact knowledge.

2. The belief that there can be no proof either that God exists or that God does not exist.
```

The idea that there is no actual way of proving either the existance or non existance of God does not fly in the face of Christianity.

Christianity is faith based, or that is to say that:

> 1. It is based on believing in things which cannot be authanticated by any of the five senses.
> 2. It derives its existance from pure belief that there is a supreme power (God), and that he controls all things, and is able to dictate events and circumstance.
> 3. It is a basic precept of Christianity that God sent his son Jesus to be an acceptable sacrifice, which would obliterate our debt of sin.
> 4. It is also a basic precept that the Holy Bible is the word of God which he himself inspired the various authors to write, and it is his unadultrated word.

The key word here is faith, if there were physical proof of the existance of God then it would no longer be faith it would be knowledge.

The best definition of faith comes from the Bible itself:

Hebrews 11:1  KJV

> Now faith is the substance of things hoped for, the evidence of things not seen.

So if God is capable of all things, you might wonder why he doesn't just give proof and be done with it, that way everyone would know and all would be just jim dandy.

Well things would not be just jim dandy:

Genesis 1:27  KJV

> So God created man in his own image, in the image of God created he him; male and female created he them.

So just what that implies is that man has the same characteristics that God has, and God has a free will, or in other words he can change his mind anytime he want's to; just like a woman does.

So if man has the same characteristics as God man must also have free will. That therefore means that man has within his power the choice to either accept or deny the sovreignty of God.

If there were proof then there would be no choice, because there would be factual backup for God's sovreignty. Could God abolish man's free will? of course he could, but then man would no longer be in the image of God.

Many Christians, and I am one, believe that God will never interfere with man's free will, and so there will never be definitive proof of God's existance. Certainly there is ample proof that the events as described in the Bible are true, but not the existance of a Supreme being.